# Rails data confirm with vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am trying to do away with jQuery in my Rails 5.1 app and move to use only Vue.js.

I have three questions in this regard:

1. Is this a sensible thing to do? Can Vue.js fully replace jQuery or should they co-exist?
2. How would I replace all the data-confirm niceties that Rails provides by default and convert them to their Vue equivalent?
3. How would I localize strings such as the data-confirm strings?

Just trying to get an idea of whether this is feasible.
Thanks!

Comment: Vue.js and jQuery are very different beasts. jQuery is a relatively low-level library that gives cross-browser API for the DOM and Ajax. Vue.js is a framework for building single-page applications. Its like comparing a wrench to a piece of ikea furniture.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Rails team removed the jQuery dependency from Rails 5.1, and [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) can be replaced with [rails-ujs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rails-ujs).

rails-ujs is written in plain JavaScript, so you can continue making a Rails + Vue.js app without jQuery.